# laravel 5.3 + Tymon\JWTAuth = How to create token with own authentication

Tags: php, jwt, laravel-5.3

Im building a Restful api, except that I DONT want to use Laravel's User authentication system (instead I use my own).

So im on stuck here:

```
$this->jwt_token = JWTAuth::attempt(['email'=>$email, 'pass'=>$pass])
```

which gives me the following **error:**

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>   App\User given, called in
>   **\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php on line 387

So how do I solve this? any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your User model isn't extending the correct Eloquent class.

Pull up your user model, and make sure it `extends Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`.

In the default Laravel install, this is imported via `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable`, then the model `extends Authenticatable`.

---

If you don't want to use the User model for authenticating, you can change which model should be used in `config/jwt.php`, but whatever you choose will need to extend the `Auth\User` class as above.

Comment: It did solve the error, however I wont be able to authenticate using `JWTAuth::attempt` as im using my own authentication. So I guess in Laravel if you do 1 thing on your own, you have to do everything else on your own as well.